# JAXB: classes generated by JAXB not recognised in context

Tags: jaxb

I am encountering this problem. Is there a fix somewhere?

Here is my file structure:

package jaxb_conainer_class;
package loader_class;

Main.java imports both loader_class and jaxb_conainer_class;

In the loader_class, a call to
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(xxxx.class);

gives me the crash above

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}default.

Comment: However, if I compile jaxb_conainer_class loader_class seperately . then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate classes from an XML schema you should create the `JAXBContext` on the generated package name.  This will ensure that the `ObjectFactory` and everything else will be picked up correctly.

```java
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.foo");
```

If there are  more than one package than you can use `:` as the delimiter.

```java
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.foo:org.example.bar");
```

Alternatively you can include the `ObjectFactory` class in the classes used to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`, but my recommendation is to use the package name(s).

Comment: Thanks. it resolves one problem but creates another one. the code now looks like JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("name");
    Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller(); 
    MClass mClass = (MClass) u.unmarshal(file); But I am seeing this error Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"M.class"). Expected elements are (none)

Comment: @user2167013 - `name` is the package name for the generated classes?  Also did the XML schema contain a global element called `M.class`?  The following example may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

Comment: Yes, "name" is the exact package name its actually "jaxb_conainer_class" in my case. Yes, the xml file has something like <m.class name="xxx"> it appears on the very first line. Another intersting thing is, if I compile the packages above seperately, everything works. Following the above example, if I do, "javac axb_conainer_class; javac Main.java", everything works. However, If I remove all the .class files and do "javac Main.java" only then I got the error.

Comment: BTW, the example you provided above. This very particular line doesn't compile JAXBElement<feedtype> feed = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(xml), FeedType.class); Here is error The method unmarshal(Node, Class<T>) in the type Unmarshaller is not applicable for the arguments (StreamSource, Class<MClass>) Thanks